# Direct and indirect narration

Tags: reported-speech

How to change the following direct sentence into indirect?
**He said, "I can not help you."**
The problem I face is that there is no object in the reporting sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem.

The indirect version really depends on who the **you** refers to.

> He said (that) he could not help me/him/her.